# Java, why is toLowerCase() not working in if condition, only print?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am Java beginner. I dont understand why .toLowerCase() is not working when placed in if condition.

A simple version of my code:

```
if ( recType.toLowerCase() == "device") {
          System.out.println("done");
      }
```

it works when recType= "device" ofcourse but when recType="Device", it doesnt convert it to "device" so whats inside the if condition is not implemented!!. Any ideas?

Comment: `toLowerCase()` returns a String, and strings are compared using the `equals(...)` method, not by an operator.

Comment: So `if ( recType.toLowerCase().equals("device") )` ...

Comment: There's also `String.equalsIgnoreCase`: `recType.equalsIgnoreCase("device")`.